# How can we achieve infinite slider/swiper like this in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-slider, flutter-swiper

Is there any library or plugin that has the feature to enable infinite scroll with a slider/swiper view like the one below? I have searched for similar sliders, but I haven't found any.
[image: infinite horizontal image slider]

Answer (score 0):

you can just use the `PageView.builder()` and not specifying the `itemCount`

```
final yourPageController= PageController(initialPage: 10000);

PageView.builder(
      controller: yourPageController,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Center(
          child: Text('page number $index'),
        );
      },
   ),
```

since I didn't specify the `itemCount`, it's now an infinite `PageView` that you can use and customize.

Comment: I want to achieve the view like the attached image. Transforming the list item similar to the above design